# Access to yum repository from computer in private subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

If I install a host within a private subnet, do I have to create a NAT instance so that I can  do a software installation from a Yum repository? I'm thinking you do, but I was hoping that amazon might have some internally hosted repo that would be accessible from within the private network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a host within a private subnet, you need a NAT instance and internet gateway for any traffic from it to leave the VPC. You can't even reach other Amazon services that live outside your VPC, such as S3, without this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon Linux you can now use [VPC Endpoints to access the yum repository](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-al1-al2-update-yum-without-internet/) from a private subnet.